# Where do I find a history of changes to Stack Exchange's API?

Tags: support, api, stack-exchange-history

As the title says is there a place where I can find a history of changes to the API?

The API I am talking about is here: https://api.stackexchange.com/

I want something more detailed than what is shown in the What's New page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the official history in [the API docs "Change Log"](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log).
Note that the "log" is very sparse, does not include every significant build, nor bug fixes nor feature requests.  A lot of changes are made silently -- including API version 2.3.

Also note that that "Change Log" omits version 1 and earlier of the API.  You can find some of that in [the *API v1.x Shutdown* timeline](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/api-v1-shutdown).

Comment: So there's not much I can get from it, just bits and pieces? Oh well thanks.

Comment: @ptestb0001, Yep. Sorry.  See https://stackapps.com/questions/8149/please-release-and-or-document-api-version-2-3 and similar feature requests.

Comment: Thank you. I would also upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep. :)

Comment: @ptestb0001, you're welcome and no problem.